# Do k8s custom resources need an operator in order to have events?

Tags: kubernetes, argo-workflows

I have created CRDs, loaded them, and created resources matching them. I am attempting to get ARGO-events to watch for it, but `kubectl get events` doesn't list the create or destroy event for the resource. I know operators can create arbitrary events, but I thought ADD REMOVE UPDATE would function natively.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is yes.  you do need an operator if you want any events on your Custom Resource.  I added the following

```
import kopf

@kopf.on.create('<GROUP>', 'v1', '<RESOURCE>')
def on_create(namespace, spec, body, logger, **kwargs):
    kopf.event(body, type='Normal',
               reason='ResourceAdded',
               message='new resource was created')
```

and now KOPF, and Custom events are listed and reported to ARGO.